# SSRS How to Start tablix at the same position of every page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a tablix that starts at the .87 on the y-axis of the first page. It will print a number of rows and columns before going to the next page. When  printing on subsequent pages, it will print at the very top of the page (y-axis 0). Is there a way to have the tablix start printing at the same spot on every page (not at the top) using the tablix: position-location property?

```
----------------------Top of page 1---------------
|
| Starts printing here with space from the top
|

---------------------Top of page 2-n--------------
|Starts printing here with no space from the top
|
|
```

Note: My margins are all set to 0. For some reason, if I add a top or bottom margin of any length to the report, it will produce an extra blank page, even though the margins + tablix size are less than the page size.

Answer (score 0):

This is little tricky ,

1. Add a page break after each page,
2. Then add a large 2 row table over the page
3. Now keep empty 1st row to manage the distance to your predefined position
4. Now insert whatever necessary to 2nd big row.

This is like everything is inside one big table row

Answer (score 0):

I ran to this issue many times and couldn't get an answer. However, I was able to solve this problem by two ways.

1. Move tablix1 under tablix2 and make sure they are 1 in tall between them. If tablix1 is 1 inch tall then tablix2 should 1 inch as well.
2. Add a rectangle between tablix and make them as small as possible and add a page break only on the rectangle. Make sure `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace` is set to `True`.